# Updating Magento Inventory through Extension on simple and complex products

Tags: magento, model, magento-1.7, inventory

I am updating the Stock on Hand Inventory Qty on a Magento store through an extension that I have developed, using the following code:

```
Mage::getModel("cataloginventory/stock_item")
  ->loadByProduct($pid)
  ->setQty($qty)
  ->save();
```

Now, from my testing, this works fine, however I am a little concerned if this is having any negative affects on the different types of product that can be created in Magento (such as simple and complex products).

Is the above the correct way to update the SOH, and do I need to handle Complex products any differently? My gut feeling is that I don't need to do anything differently with complex products as they all end up deriving from a Simple product which has its own Stock on Hand?

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 3):

As long as you only update simples you'll be fine like this. Indeed all other non-virtual product types derive their stock from the simples.

You might even want to add

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel("cataloginventory/stock_item")
    ->loadByProduct($pid)
    ->setQty($qty);

if ($stockItem->getCanBackInStock() && $stockItem->getQty() > $stockItem->getMinQty()) {
    $stockItem->setIsInStock(true)
        ->setStockStatusChangedAutomaticallyFlag(true);
}

$stockItem->save();
```

See `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock::backItemQty()` to see how Magento adds stock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've looked into `backItemQty()` and the problem from what I can see is that this function calls `addQty()`, which does `$this->setQty($this->getQty()+$qty);`: I want to update the Stock figure, not add or subtract to it.

Comment: Yes that is true. But setting it in your case will suffice and not have side effects as far as I could see.